# display user specific data after login classic asp

Tags: session, asp-classic, database-connection

I have this code for my project and i want the user to be directed to their account page which displays data specific to them. ie their list of suppliers.  I realise i need to create a session variable but i dont know where to put it in my code and i dont know the code to specify the user in the account page.  Can anyone help? Here is my code.

```
<%
'Connection String
Dim Conn
'Query to be executed
Dim SQLQuery
'Recordset
Dim rs
'StudentNo Of Logged in user
Dim UserName
'Password of User
Dim Password

'Getting information from submitted form
UserName = request.form("username")
Password = request.form("password")
RememberMe = request.form("rememberme")

'If not blank Username password submitted
if UserName <> "" or Password <> "" then  

'Creating connection Object    
set Conn=server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")

'Creating Recordset Object    
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")    

'Initialising Provider String    
connStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="& Server.MapPath("database.mdb")&";"   


'Opening Connection to Database    
Conn.open  connStr        
'Query to be executed    
SQLQuery = "select * from customers_tbl where c_email = '"&UserName&"' AND c_password = '"&Password&"'"   
'Retrieving recordset by executing SQL   
set rs=Conn.execute(SQLQuery)    
'If no records retrieved    
if rs.BOF and rs.EOF then        
Response.Redirect "customerlogin.htm?username=" & UserName    
else         
'If remember me selected        
if RememberMe = "ON" then
'Writing cookies permanently            
Response.Cookies("UserName")=UserName            
Response.Cookies("Password")=Password            
Response.Cookies("UserName").Expires = Now() + 365            
Response.Cookies("Password").Expires = Now() + 365            
Response.Redirect "customeraccount.htm"
else
'writing cookies temporarily            
    Response.Cookies("UserName")=UserName            
    Response.Cookies("Password")=Password            
    Response.Redirect "customeraccount.htm"
end if        
'Closing all database connections        
Conn.Close       
rs.close          
set rs = nothing        
set Conn = nothing    
end if
else    
'Invalid User    
Response.Redirect "customerlogin.htm?UserName=blank"
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the primary key of your Customers table is called CustomerId then you could have something like

```
if rs.BOF and rs.EOF then        
Response.Redirect "customerlogin.htm?username=" & UserName    
else
Session("CustomerId") = rs("customerid")
```

Then on your customeraccount page you could have a query

```
SQLQuery = "select * from customers_tbl where customerid = "&Session("CustomerId")
```

Two things I notice about your code.

First, you seem to have asp pages with the .htm extension rather than the .asp extension.  Presumably you've changed the relevant IIS settings so that it treats .htm pages as if they were ASP rather than flat html

Second, you're using the ODBC connection string.  This will work but the OLEDB driver is considered to be quicker - eg

```
connstr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=""& Server.MapPath("database.mdb")
```